# Limiting window width of Summary Box

Tags: output-formatting, undocumented, elided-forms

I am creating objects in *Mathematica*, which I'd like to compactly display in the front end notebook as a `SummaryBox`.  However, in many cases, the items that I wish to display are lengthy, and I'd like to simply limit the display width of the `SummaryBox`.

Here's how I define how `MyObject` formats:

```
ClearAll[MyObject];

MyObject /: MakeBoxes[obj:MyObject[asc_], form : (StandardForm|TraditionalForm)] :=
  Module[{above}, 
    above = 
      {{BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Name: ", asc["Name"]}]},
       {BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Expression: ", asc["Expression"]}]}};
    BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[MyObject, obj, None, above, {}, form, 
      "Interpretable" -> Automatic]
  ];
```

Then

```
MyObject[<|"Name" -> "My particular object", "Expression" -> 
  8 a^3 b + 8 a b^3 + 8 a^3 c + 24 a b^2 c + 24 a b c^2 + 8 a c^3 + 
  24 a^2 b d + 8 b^3 d + 24 a^2 c d + 24 b^2 c d + 24 b c^2 d + 
  8 c^3 d + 24 a b d^2 + 24 a c d^2 + 8 b d^3 + 8 c d^3|>]`
```

renders as:

[image]

which is **much too** wide!  How do I limit the width of a `SummaryBox` so that lengthy values just take multiple lines like this?

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Short can help, too. I tend to apply that to lengthy things I want to put in a SummaryBox

Comment: @b3m2a1 yes, I will use a combination of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically @Kuba's answer from his comment:

```
MyObject /: MakeBoxes[obj:MyObject[asc_], form_] := With[
    {
    above = {
        {BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Name: ", asc["Name"]}]},
        {
        Pane[
            Row[{Style["Expression: ", "SummaryItemAnnotation"], asc["Expression"]}],
            {300, Automatic},
            BaselinePosition->Baseline
        ]
        }
    }
    },
    BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
        MyObject,
        obj,
        None,
        above,
        {},
        form,
        "Interpretable"->Automatic
    ]
]
```

And your example:

```
MyObject[
    <|
        "Name"->"My particular object",
        "Expression"->8 a^3 b+8 a b^3+8 a^3 c+24 a b^2 c+24 a b c^2+8 a c^3+
            24 a^2 b d+8 b^3 d+24 a^2 c d+24 b^2 c d+24 b c^2 d+8 c^3 d+
            24 a b d^2+24 a c d^2+8 b d^3+8 c d^3
    |>
]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I need!  I'll give others a chance before accepting this answer.